# switch between viewcontroller and Tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am building an application which needs both a viewcontroller and a tab bar controller.

When I start the application it should load view controller (which is login screen) and from there I need to go to the tabbar controller view where the actual application starts.

Here is what I have tried:

***appdelegate.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IeAppDelegate
        : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;

    UITabBarController *tabBarController;

    UIViewController *LoginController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *LoginController;

@end
```

***appdelegate.m***

```
@synthesize window;

@synthesize tabBarController;

@synthesize LoginController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.

    LoginController = [[LoginController alloc] init];
    [window LoginController.view];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I am receiving these errors and warnings. What am I doing wrong?

```
warning: 'UIViewController' may not respond to '-alloc'
warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
warning: '...' as arguments.)
error: expected ']' before '.' token
warning: 'UIWindow' may not respond to '-LoginController'
```

---

**Update:** I figured out one error:

```
LoginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
```

But in this statement:

```
[window LoginController.view];
```

I still get:

```
error: expected ']' before '.' token
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a tabbar app. In the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions portion of your app delegate you'll add your viewcontroller to the window, covering up the tabbar and everything else. It'll look like this:

```
// Initialize your login view controller
yourLoginViewController = [[YourLoginViewController alloc] init];

// Add in the tab controller 
// (this code should already be there if you started with the template)
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];

// In front of that add in your login view controller
[window yourLoginViewController.view];

// Finally, display the whole thing (this should also already be there)
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```